# Determinants of matrices with constrained entries

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Let $A \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, written $A = (a_{i,j})$.  Define the Height of $A$ to be $\max_{i,j} |a_{i,j}|$.  The Laplace expansion of $\det(A)$ clearly implies that if $A$ has height $N \in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{equation*}
|\det(A)| \leq \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} |\prod_{i \leq n} a_{i,\sigma(i)}| \leq n!N^n.
\end{equation*}
The order of magnitude in $N$ is even sharp, as is obvious from the example:
\begin{equation*}
A := \begin{pmatrix} N & N & \cdots & N \\ -N & N & \cdots & N \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ -N & -N & \cdots & N
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where in the $j$th row, we let the first $j-1$ components be $-N$, for $j \geq 2$.  In this case, adding the first row to each of the subsequent rows produces an upper triangular matrix with components $2N$ at all diagonal elements except the top left one, and the determinant is therefore $2^{n-1}N!$ (obviously the diagonal matrix with entries all equal to $N$ is another such example, but I wanted to further motivate the question and strategy below).  I was curious to know if there was a sharper bound $|\det(A)| \leq C(n)N^n$ than $n!$ that can be deduced.  My first strategy was to consider some different arrangement of signs in the example above, say by defining some function $\epsilon(i,j) = \pm 1$ on the indices $(i,j)$ of the matrix and then trying to determine a suitable choice for $\epsilon$ so that the exponent of $-1$ in the Laplace expansion, $\text{inv}(\sigma) + \sum_{i \leq n} \epsilon(i,\sigma(i))$ was even for a large proportion of permutations, but I do not see a good construction.
Any hints would be appreciated (though please do not provide a full solution if you have one).

Comment: Note that $\det(A)=\pm 1$ for $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$. Your examples are not in this group, because the inverse has no integral coefficients.

Comment: Presumably what is meant is simply the $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb Z$.  In fact, I don't think $\mathbb Z$ plays much of a role here: any suitable inequality of this form should also work for entries in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The given example has determinant $2^{n-1} N^n$, not $2^{n-1} N!$.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant is bounded by the product of the $\ell^2$ norms of the rows, so
$\det(A) \le n^{n/2} N^n$.

EDIT: ... and this bound is sharp for some $n$, maybe for all multiples of $4$.  See [Hadamard matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix)